# Warning during Snap application install

Tags: snap, visual-studio-code

I have Kubuntu 21.10.

To install VSCode from Snap:

- I open Discover
- search for vscode
- click on 'Install from Snap'
- enter sudo password
- the following warning appear: `This Snap application i not compatible with security sandboxing and will have full access to this computer. Install it anyway?`

What does it mean? Why does it appear only for some apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's fine. Snaps can be sandboxed*. That works fine when an app can work in a sandbox. For example, a simple game would work fine in a sandbox.

But... VS Code wouldn't really work in a sandbox. It's a code editor, so it can edit any file, and it has a built-in terminal as well. As a result, it doesn't really work in a sandbox. So, Snap gives you a warning that it won't run in a sandbox. If you're fine with that, you can just say yes.

More generally, you'll get that message when an app won't work in a sandbox. Some common types of apps that won't work in a sandbox are apps like terminal emulators and code editors, as they need full system access.

**Whether or not the sandbox works well/is secure is a separate question.*

---

The OP also asked why it doesn't ask with the `--classic` argument. Let's look at the [manpage for the `snap` command](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/snapd/snap.8.en.html#classic)**:

```
--classic
    Put snap in classic mode and disable security confinement
```

So, because the `--classic` argument disable security confinement (a.k.a. the sandbox), `snap` doesn't prompt you because you've already specified that you want to disable it.

***You may notice that I linked to the Debian manpage, not the Ubuntu one. It doesn't make a difference, but the Debian one lets me link to the specific argument I want, and Ubuntu is based on Debian, so linking to the Debian manpage is fine.*

Comment: Thank you @cocomac! Do you know why I receive no warning if I install vscode from snap from the terminal? I mean `sudo snap install --classic code`?

Comment: @JBach I've updated my answer to explain why. Does my edit address your question?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!